# In hive how to convert a string to number where the number is formatted and string for hours

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

In hive how to convert a string to number where the number is formatted and string for hour ?

Samples :

String with formatted to integer

40.868.031  => 40868031

String to hour

0:06:52.203954  => 00:06:52

Comment: Split it to 2 posts

Comment: For removing dots from integer use `select translate('40.868.031','.','') `